# redirect to payment express site from actionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway

I'm trying to open Payment express site when use click on billing submit button. for this I have written this code

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Billing()   
        {
            string URI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paymentexpressUrl"].ToString();

            var PxPayUserId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PxPayUserId"].ToString();
            var PxPayKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PxPayKey"].ToString();

            // form the PXPost Xml message
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            xtw.WriteStartElement("Txn");
            xtw.WriteElementString("PostUsername", PxPayUserId);
            xtw.WriteElementString("PostPassword", PxPayKey);
            xtw.WriteElementString("Amount", "100");
            xtw.WriteElementString("InputCurrency", "USD");
            xtw.WriteElementString("TxnType", "Purchase");
            xtw.WriteElementString("TxnId", "");
            xtw.WriteElementString("MerchantReference", "Test Transaction");
            xtw.WriteEndElement();
            xtw.Close();



            // Send the Xml message to PXPost
            WebRequest wrq = WebRequest.Create(URI);
            wrq.Method = "POST";
            wrq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
            wrq.ContentLength = b.Length;

            Stream s = wrq.GetRequestStream();
            s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            s.Close();

            return wrq;
        }
```

But don't how to redirect it to payment express site. 
How can i do this.

Comment: What Exactly you are trying to do ?
Which Payment Express are you talking about ? URL ?
Havent they provided the API Documents for the same ?

Comment: @bhuvin: I'm using this [Payment Gateway](http://www.paymentexpress.com/Technical_Resources/SampleCode_ASPDotNET/PxPost.aspx)

There is form in my view, when user click on submit button then I want User to redirect on payment gateway site to make payment.

Comment: So now, you want to Redirect to Payment express's site ,wherein the User fills in Details and then Move ahead with the Payment ?

Comment: @bhuvin: Yes. 
Have you checked that [payment gateway site](http://www.paymentexpress.com/Technical_Resources/SampleCode_ASPDotNET/PxPost.aspx)

Right now I'm assiging dummy data.

Comment: Amit could you check this out? This is what you want -http://www.paymentexpress.com/Technical_Resources/Ecommerce_Hosted/PxPay_2_0

Comment: In case it suffices, the Request let me know, so that i can post the same as the Answer.

Comment: @bhuvin: Hii . I'm doing the same. I have generated the XML now how to redirect to site .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82280/discussion-between-bhuvin-and-amit-kumar).

Comment: If this worked for you, in that case please mark the same as the Answer. Else please tell me where did exactly u faced the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See what you were trying to Do is Using their own Component to Go through payment. 
Please download the Sample code from the [Given Link](http://www.paymentexpress.com/Downloads/PxPay2_CSDotNet35.zip/) and Hence you will be able to Solve the same. (Check the Whole Code. They have added the same since this works.) Also find the Relevant Link for the whole Documentation regarding the same : [Link to documentation](http://www.paymentexpress.com/Technical_Resources/Ecommerce_Hosted/PxPay_2_0).